# An environment to change the vertical space around a formula

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations, line-breaking

Specially in beamer presentations, I use a custom environment to change the vertical space around a formula. The code is:

```
\newenvironment{shrinkeq}[1]
{ \bgroup
  \addtolength\abovedisplayshortskip{#1}
  \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{#1}
  \addtolength\belowdisplayshortskip{#1}
  \addtolength\belowdisplayskip{#1}}
{\egroup}
```

However, an unwanted horizontal space is added in front of the text following the formula. For example, the code

```
Text before text before text before\dots
\[ \int_{a_1}^{b_1}f(x)dx+\int_{a_2}^{b_2}g(x)dx+\int_{a_3}^{b_3}h(x)dx=0 \]
Text after text after text after\dots
\bigskip

Text before text before text before\dots
\begin{shrinkeq}{-2ex}
\[ \int_{a_1}^{b_1}f(x)dx+\int_{a_2}^{b_2}g(x)dx+\int_{a_3}^{b_3}h(x)dx=0 \]
\end{shrinkeq}
Text after text after text after\dots
```

produces

[image]

The issue can be fixed by putting a `\null` after `\end{shrinkeq}` but I do not understand why this works.

¿Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7):

Line breaks cause white space, like blanks do. Note the line break between `\end{shrinkeq}` and the following text.

A local solution would be commenting out the line break: `\end{shrinkeq}%`

A global solution would be adding `\ignorespacesafterend` to the end of your environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{shrinkeq}[1]
{ \bgroup
  \addtolength\abovedisplayshortskip{#1}
  \addtolength\abovedisplayskip{#1}
  \addtolength\belowdisplayshortskip{#1}
  \addtolength\belowdisplayskip{#1}}
{\egroup\ignorespacesafterend}
```

This definition causes that blanks and line breaks directly following the environment would be ignored.

Comment: Thank you Stefan! I did not know the <code>\ignorespacesafterend</code> command.